# How to handle timezones in timestamps in R?

Tags: date, csv, r

I have non-UTC timezone times given as 17th August 2016 at 21:41 at Swedish timezone (UTC+1). 
I have two of such recordings for each entry. 
I am thinking how to record them nicely in CSV file. 
I thought first to convert them manually to Unix timestamps, but then, started to think about maintaining the original timezone etc `170820162141` together with separate column for the timezone. 
But still, I think those versions are not any standards. 
I do know how to generate Unix timestamps based on the thread [How can I generate Unix timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1204669/54964) where the following command structure can work also here.

```
% https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764285/54964
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"
```

I am going to read the CSV file with `R`/`Bash`/`Zsh`/.... 
My proposal

- Custom timemark etc the former one such as `170820162141` without seconds
- Separate column for timezone etc `UTC+1`

CSV file example

```
Time_start, Time_end, Time_start_timezone
170820162141, 180820160901, UTC+1
```

Test function pseudocode

```
Count time difference between two custom timestamps.
```

### Iterating thrig's proposal

I changed data to

1. Addition of the timezone `+0100` (UTC+1) in `, , , 03012011-2011+0100, 03022011-2011+0100`.
2. Format `strptime(from,format="%d%m%Y-%H%M%z` where I added `%z` about the timezone.
3. Printing `data` gives all times correctly if timezone is set correctly to the given data.

Code run by `Rscript script.r` on five column data where time data at two last columns

```
library('methods')
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363290/16920
setClass('iso8601')

#03012011-2011
setAs("character","iso8601",function(from) strptime(from,format="%d%m%Y-%H%M%z"))
data <- read.csv("/home/masi/Documents/Data/log.csv", colClasses=c(NA, NA, NA, "iso8601","iso8601"), header=TRUE) # my particular case

data
```

Output: perfect! I had to adjust timezone correctly to my data, since my timezone changes often.

- Without `library('methods')`, you get `Rscript Error: could not find function "setClass"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 8601 is one possible format; it can contain a timezone offset and can be parsed with e.g. `strptime` in various languages.

```
$ cat x
2017-05-05T18:25:28+0100,2017-05-05T18:33:22+0100,foo
2017-05-05T18:34:21+0100,2017-05-05T18:38:52+0100,bar
$ R -q --silent --no-save
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)"
> setClass('iso8601')
> setAs("character","iso8601",function(from) strptime(from,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"))
> data=read.csv("x",colClasses=c("iso8601","iso8601",NA),header=FALSE)
> data
                   V1                  V2  V3
1 2017-05-05 17:25:28 2017-05-05 17:33:22 foo
2 2017-05-05 17:34:21 2017-05-05 17:38:52 bar
>
```

And `date` and such can generate ISO 8601 formatted dates:

```
$ date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
2017-05-05T19:20:58+0000
$ TZ=US/Pacific date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
2017-05-05T12:21:10-0700
$
```